# Angular Reactive Forms FormArray - Add button to open another pop up form

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, popup, reactive, formarray

I am trying to implement the following scenario. I have a form with input controls. One element is a formarray. This formarray has few input controls. Add button to create this formarray. When Add button is clicked, a new pop up or modal should appear to fill out the values. Is it possible using ngx bootstrap or angular material or with ngtemplateOutlet or ngcontainer. Advice please.Is it possible to collect the entire submission in a model.

Comment: what u have done till now??

Comment: These answers do not seem to answer my question. I have the main form. It has a form array. In all the web sites I see that this form array controls are created in the same form when add button is clicked. But for me, this formarray control should nbe shown in a pop up modal each time add button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Complete Working [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialog-form-array?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadd-question-dialog.ts)

First You need your form array component lets say this...

```
ngOnInit() {
this.form = this.fb.group({
  questions: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
        questionNumber: new FormControl(this.data.questionCount + 1, { validators: [Validators.required] }),
        type: new FormControl('paragraph'),
        text: new FormControl('', { updateOn: 'blur', validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]})
      }),
    ]),
})
```

}

and in app.component you can get data back and open Mat-Dialog like this...

```
openDialog() {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddQuestionDialog, {
  width: '600px',
  data: { questionCount: 0 }
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('The dialog was closed', result);
  this.animal = result;
});
```

For, more complete working example you can find on above stack-blitz link...

Answer (score 0):

I think angular material MatDialog will be useful for you. You will have to create a component for the values which will be collected and on the modal close subscribe to the data and push it to your formarry.
A good starting point will be the agular material [guide](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this blog post will help to do my task. Only thing is I need to use ngx bootstrap or material to add pop up modals.

[https://www.brophy.org/post/nested-reactive-forms-in-angular2/][1]